# Is there a gem that will send emails upon uncaught exceptions in a ruby on rails 2.3.8 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Exception notification is rails 3, so I was wondering if there was a rails 2.3.8 gem for email notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exception_notification plugin is available for Rails 2.3, just [on a different branch](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/2-3-stable).

You could also get [Exceptional](http://www.getexceptional.com/) or [Airbrake](http://airbrakeapp.com/).